# AFNetworking 2.0 how to put some parameters in the query string of a POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I need to call a ws to send an image to a server. 
 Who mades the webserver, decided that the session token should be sent trough the URL and not in the body. 
The query should look like: `http://api.service.com/imageupload.php?token=434353435` and in the body there should be the image with its parameter.
The session manager when I use the `-POST` methods puts all the parameter inside the body.
Is there a way to say to the request serializer to put some parameters in the query string and others in the body? or do I need to subclass it?

Comment: You should just add the token parameter to the URL string yourself. Not elegant, but simple.

Comment: Thx, Rob, I know that I could, but I was wondering if there is some more reliable method, since the token won't be the only one.

Comment: Then a category or subclass will do the job. But this is not something that AFNetworking does for you.

Comment: @Andrea, i need same thing as you, how did you resolve this? Can you please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369987/afnetworking-send-parameter-as-query-string-in-post-request

Comment: @Bharat as far ad I remember I just added the token in the URL string and encoded like this AFHTTPRequestOperation * op = [self POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@",ADBOOMApiImageUploadURL,ADBOOMParameterTicketID,[self.currentToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {, but the good way is to subclass the AFHTTPRequestSerializer

Comment: I did this
`NSString* encodedUrl = [@"http://192.168.4.1/config?command=plugs" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:encodedUrl parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {        
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            }];` , but got bad request

Comment: @Andrea Subclassing `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` also didn't helped me. In case you get some time, can you please have a look into [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369987/afnetworking2-send-parameter-as-query-string-in-post-request). May be it just matter of few minutes for you and would be great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this

```
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"Google.com" stringByAppendingString:AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(parameters, NSUTF8StringEncoding)]]] ;
```

Where parameters is a dictionary

Comment: Hi Saqib thx for the answer, I do agree that this could work, but as Mattt said in this issue this should be used only internally.  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1536