# AFNetworking2 send parameter as query string in POST request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I need to send query string in URL as well as JSON in body while making POST request.To send query string in url i override `HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI` property as suggested in [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794573/afnetworking-2-0-send-post-request-with-url-parameters/23660823#23660823) like

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl]];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        manager.requestSerializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"POST", @"GET", @"HEAD", @"PUT", @"DELETE"]];



        [manager POST:fullUrl parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 }];
```

but it seems doing this add my JSON data into URL as well, hence my request is not executed on server.But i need to send only 'command' parameter into url and some JSON data into request body.
 my `fullUrl` string is looks like http://some_ip_address/config?command=some_command and param is `NSDictionary` object.
Note that there is a parameter in `fullUrl` i.e. **command** and i also send a `NSDictionary` object as **param** in

```
[manager POST:fullUrl parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     }];
```

**Edit2:** I also tried with `NSURLSession`

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my_server_ip/config?command=plugs"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param options:0 error:&error];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
```

but get **status code: 400 in NSURLResponse.**

**Edit3:** someone suggested to subclass `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` class in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052480/afnetworking-2-0-how-to-put-some-parameters-in-the-query-string-of-a-post-reques) so i tried with

```
@implementation CustomAFHTTPRequestSerializer

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                     error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSString* encodedUrl = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSError *error1;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error1];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
     return request;
}
@end
```

And assign it as requestSerializer of operationManager

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.requestSerializer = [[CustomAFHTTPRequestSerializer alloc] init];
```

But still get `Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)`

Please help me guys, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: command is your parameter and http://some_ip_address/config -- this is your full URL correct

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes, you get it correct.

Comment: Maybe it sounds stupid, but are you sure that the request is correct, have you tried to print it and check with a working one. AFNetworking provides a logger class that you can add to your project https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger

Comment: @Andrea I can confirm that request is correct because it is working on Android and i have cross checked parameter with android team. Also if i override `HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI` property then there is no bad request error, but it is not useful for me because it add all the parameter to URL, hence server fails to response. May be i'm doing something wrong.